# How do we authenticate Quickbooks Online in a Console Application?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, console-application, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to invoke Quick Books Online API in a console application where i need to get the bearer token first. Below is the code snippet where i'm trying to get authorization code first for subsequent access token calls. I'm getting a HTML response instead of json object with auth code.

Also, What are the grant types does QBO support ?

```cs
HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();            
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler,false);
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2");

List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> param = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
param.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("response_type","code"));
param.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "AB5********26"));
param.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting"));
param.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", "https://developer.intuit.com/v2/OAuth2Playground/RedirectUrl"));

var resp = httpClient.PostAsync("", new FormUrlEncodedContent(param)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var result = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

HTML Response for the request i sent..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="dj_mac is-not-mobile" data-shell-type="node">
<!-- node-shell -->

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="google-site-verIfication" content="hiEXDzwqUxxMY5KZkAkeHBn6J0gy2Ne1gJdm77RkGbk">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#0098cd">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="preload"
        href="https://plugin.intuitcdn.net/sbg-web-shell-ui/11.24.0/bower_components/document-register-element/build/document-register-element.js"
        as="script">
    <link rel="preload" href="https://plugin.intuitcdn.net/sbg-web-shell-ui/11.24.0/dojo/dojo.js" as="script">
    <link rel="preload" href="https://plugin.intuitcdn.net/sbg-web-shell-ui/11.24.0/shell/boot.js" as="script">
    <link rel="preload" href="https://plugin.intuitcdn.net/sbg-web-shell-ui/11.24.0/dojo/resources/blank.gif"
        as="image">
    <link rel="preload" href="https://plugin.intuitcdn.net/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
        as="script">
    <link rel="preload" href="https://plugin.intuitcdn.net/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js" as="script">
    <script>
        (function() {var e = document.createEvent("Event");e.initEvent("load", true, false);window.dispatchEvent(e);})();
    </script>
    <link rel="preload" href="https://plugin.intuitcdn.net/ua-parser-js/0.7.20/dist/ua-parser.min.js" as="script">
    <meta id="viewPortMetaTag" name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">


    <meta name="application-name" content="QuickBooks App Store">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="QuickBooks App Store">

    <title>QuickBooks App Store</title>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://plugin.intuitcdn.net/sbg-web-shell-ui/11.24.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

</head>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://plugin.intuitcdn.net/sbg-web-shell-ui/11.24.0/bower_components/document-register-element/build/document-register-element.js">
</script>
</head>

<body class="en-us">


    <script type="text/javascript" nonce="bTjY6kTz1OvXs0b/7WA0RA==">
        try {

        require({cache: {}});
        require(["shell/base/loader", "shell/applications/default/config"], function(loader, config) {
            var runtime = {"isWebpack":false,"embedded":false,"ecosystem":false,"accessDeniedPages":[48],"hiddenPages":[]};
            loader.load({
                useLayers: true,
                storageSecondaryKey: "",
                storagePrimaryKey: "",
                platformPlugin: appContext.pluginsInfo && appContext.pluginsInfo.plugins ? appContext.pluginsInfo.plugins["qbo-ui-platform"] : null,
                layers: config.getLayers(runtime)
            }, config.getAppHandler(runtime));
        });

            } catch (error){
                console.error(error);

        require({cache: {}});
        require(["shell/base/loader", "shell/applications/default/config"], function(loader, config) {
            var runtime = {"isWebpack":false,"embedded":false,"ecosystem":false,"accessDeniedPages":[48],"hiddenPages":[]};
            loader.load({
                useLayers: true,
                storageSecondaryKey: "",
                storagePrimaryKey: "",
                platformPlugin: appContext.pluginsInfo && appContext.pluginsInfo.plugins ? appContext.pluginsInfo.plugins["qbo-ui-platform"] : null,
                layers: config.getLayers(runtime)
            }, config.getAppHandler(runtime));
        });

            };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Usually to get a bearer token you first call an authentication API with REST (i.e. call a web service with a login and a password) and it returns the bearer token. Then you use that in subsequent calls.

Comment: Have you gone through this and dissected how it works? https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/build-your-first-app as-is, your question is not detailed enough for anyone to answer

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i've modifed my question. please let me know your thoughts...

Comment: Please add the HTML response to your question

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid updated html response in answers...

Comment: Don't put it in an answer, put it in the question. I'll do it for you

Comment: Not too sure at this point. If the quick start says this is mean to work then you'll need to go ask their support or wait around here for someone who has a better idea